# How to check whether a decimal value has no more than 2 decimal points?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, decimal

I have a method as below:

```
public bool IsValid(decimal rate)
{
  // 
}
```

The rate can be between 0.00 and 99.99 and it shouldn't contain more than 2 decimal places otherwise it should throw an exception.

How to check whether a decimal value has no more than 2 decimal points? e.g. 99.123 is invalid whereas 99.12 is valid.,

Comment: Answer depends on where the checking happens. If you are checking it on input from the user, validate the input string with regex before converting it to a number.

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
return decimal.Round(rate, 2) == rate;
```

Note that this would still return true for 100.000m which is a distinct value from 100.00m, and will show up with all three decimal digits if you call `ToString`.

Answer (score 6):

```
public bool IsValid(decimal rate)
{
    return rate%0.01m == 0;
}
```

This will return true if rate modulo .01 is 0 (which it always will be if the decimal is a number that contains only one or two decimal places). Three decimal places are more will return false (UNLESS the third decimal place is a 0, EX: 2.220 will return true in this case). I'm not sure what you are planning on using this for, but if that is an acceptable failure case this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsValid(decimal rate){
    int temp = rate * 100;
    decimal temp2 = temp / (decimal)100;
    return temp2 == rate;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim s.myscript As String
dim text_value as double = "12.345" 
s = text_value.ToString
' Split string based on dot
words = s.Split(New Char() {"."c})
'if array contain decimal
If words.Length > 1 Then
If (words(1).Length > 2) = True Then
 myscript = "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please enter 2 decimal places only!');</script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onclick", myscript)

Exit Sub
End If
End If
```